# how to add different id for multiple rectangles which is created in fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

hi i am using fabricjs for dragging and resizing of rectangles. the working is, when i click a button a rectangle is formed . for each button click i can add each rectangle. i want add different style for each rectangle. for that i try to add different id/class for each rectangle. but it is not working. this is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="fabric.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #c{

            background-color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    <button id="my-image" onclick="myFunction()">click</button>

    <script>
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { width: 500, height: 400, });
        var click = 0;
        $('#my-image').click(myFunction);

        function myFunction() {
            click += 1;

            var imgElement = document.getElementById('my-image');
            var rect = new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 50, fill: 'green' });
        rect.setAttribute("class", click);

            canvas.add(rect);

            };

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

what is wrong in my code?

Comment: The problem is you are using jQuery and you have not included it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the jQuery library as you are using jQuery code:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="fabric.min.js"></script>
```

and

1. you can remove the inline event handler `onclick`.
2. You can create a doc ready block for it although your code will work as it is below the elements, but it would be nice to have it.

Comment: i already add the jquary library . the error is "Uncaught TypeError: rect.setAttribute is not a function"

Comment: @aswathy I suppose you need to see the `console.log(rect);` if this is your canvas element then it should add the attribute and if this is an object then you have to set the property in the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can set id for each item by adding the below code in all.js file

In the fabric.js build version 1.3.0 : In the Object declaration add

```
 var object = {
   id:   this.id,
   remaining properties in all.js
  }
```

Now you can set the object id with:

`canvas.getActiveObject().id`=your id value;
You can retrieve the object id with :

```
Myid= canvas.getActiveObject().get('id');
```

So, in this way we add multiple id for rectangle which is created in fabric.js

Comment: now i have only fabric.min.js  , is there any more file need?

Comment: make sure you having jquery-ui.min.js then give a try

Comment: i can't use jquery-ui

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever check the console for errors? Trying your code i get the error "setAttribute is not a function". Probably because your var rect is not an Element in the DOM you could call this method on. The example below with your code slightly modified seems to work... although I don't have a background about fabric.js

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { width: 500, height: 150, });
var click = 0;

$('#my-image').click(myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    click += 1;

    var imgElement = document.getElementById('my-image');
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 50, fill: 'green' });
    $(rect).addClass(click);
    canvas.add(rect);

};
```

```css
#c{background-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<button id="my-image" onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Further it looks like you want to create a unique class name for each new rectangle. I would use an id for this purpose and not a class.